# Fix the logic for proper comparison using a Map

Tags: apex, list, map

I'm trying to check and change the `Client__c` value in `Mopping__c` if the `In_date__c` has changed in the needed `Rent__c`. There is a lot of data, therefore `Map` is used.

Structure: if `Mopping 1` is related to `Rent 1` which is related to `Opportunity 1`, and `Out_date__c` of the `Mopping 1` `==` `In_date__c` of `Rent 2` which is too related to `Opportunity 1`, `Client__c` of `Mopping 1` should be equals to `Client__c` of `Rent 2`.

But! If `In_date__c` of `Rent 2` is changed and `!=` to `Out_date__c` of the `Mopping 1`, `Client__c` of `Mopping 1` should be `null` again. Now it doesn't work and the `Client__c` value doesn't change.

My code:

```
public void updatingHelper(){
    List<Mopping__c> moppingsToUpdate = new List<Mopping__c>();
    List<Rent__c> rentals = new List<Rent__c>([SELECT Id, Client__c, In_date__c, Opportunity__c FROM Rent__c]);

    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Date, List<Rent__c>> dateRentMap = new Map<Date, List<Rent__c>>();

    for(Rent__c rent : rentals){
        Date rentInDate = Date.newinstance(rent.In_date__c.year(), rent.In_date__c.month(), rent.In_date__c.day());
        oppIds.add(rent.Opportunity__c);

        if(!dateRentMap.containsKey(rentInDate)){
            List<Rent__c> listRentals = new List<Rent__c>();
            listRentals.add(rent);
            dateRentMap.put(rentInDate, listRentals); 
        } else{
            List<Rent__c> existListRentals = dateRentMap.get(rentInDate);
            existListRentals.add(rent);
            dateRentMap.put(rentInDate, existListRentals);
        }
    }

    List<Mopping__c> moppings = [SELECT Id, Client__c, Out_date__c, Rent__r.Opportunity__c FROM Mopping__c WHERE Rent__r.Opportunity__c IN : oppIds];

    for(Mopping__c mopping : moppings){
        Date moppingOutDate = Date.newinstance(mopping.Out_date__c.year(), mopping.Out_date__c.month(), mopping.Out_date__c.day());
        //I have to check all rentals to clear mopping.Client__c if the In_date__c has changed in the needed rent.
        //But here I get only correct Rentals, where In_date__c == mopping's Out_date__c:
        List<Rent__c> neededRentals = dateRentMap.get(moppingOutDate);

        if(neededRentals != null){
            for(Rent__c neededRent : neededRentals){
                Date rentInDate = Date.newinstance(neededRent.In_date__c.year(), neededRent.In_date__c.month(), neededRent.In_date__c.day());

                if(mopping.Rent__r.Opportunity__c == neededRent.Opportunity__c && moppingOutDate == rentInDate &&
                   mopping.Client__c != String.valueOf(neededRent.Client__c)){
                       mopping.Client__c = String.valueOf(neededRent.Client__c);
                       moppingsToUpdate.add(mopping);
                 //So this check is useless: moppingOutDate is always equals to rentInDate:
                 } else if(mopping.Rent__r.Opportunity__c == neededRent.Opportunity__c && moppingOutDate != rentInDate){
                        mopping.Client__c = '';
                        moppingsToUpdate.add(mopping);   
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    if(!moppingsToUpdate.isEmpty()){
        update moppingsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Hi Martin. Updated. It's in code comments too : "But! If In_date__c of Rent 2 is changed and != to Out_date__c of the Mopping 1, Client__c of Mopping 1 should be null again. Now it doesn't work and the Client__c value doesn't change."

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand everything, or that this will solve all your problems, but there are two main changes I would make. Rather than looping through all the needed rentals for the move out date of Mopping, you should group the Rentals by their Opportunities instead, and loop through all the Rent__c records that have the same Opp as the Mopping record (as you're looping through the Mopping records). Then, for each Rent__c record that does not have the same Id as the Mopping__r.Rent__c Id, you should check if their move in date is the same as the Mopping's.

Comment: If so, then set client__c to the Rent's Client. If none of them have the same move in date as the Mopping's move out date, clear it out (use a boolean to check if any match the move out date and set the boolean to true; if it is still false after looping through the Rents, none of them matched the move out date). If this works for you, or you like a more detailed code answer, I'll write it up as an answer (I am just leaving it as a comment for now as I don't know if it will work or if I understood your issue correctly)